# @TenantId referenced by @JoinColumns

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities with fields `tenantId`, each annotated with `@TenantId`. In one of the entities I have a Unidirectional OneToMany relationship with the other entity based on a column value:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "value", referencedColumnName = "value")
  private List<EntityB> entities;
```

I want to modify this relationship so that only entities that also share a tenantID are related:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "tenantId", referencedColumnName = "tenantId"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "value", referencedColumnName = "value")
  })
  private List<EntityB> entities;
```

However when I do this my application throws a `org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Still need to wire in composite in-memory value generation` error.

I am able to do a single `@JoinColumn` on tenantId, and a multiple `@JoinColumns` on values other than tenantId, but can't get tenantID annotated with `@TenantId` to work in a `@JoinColumns`

Comment: Just to begin with, you should re-test with 6.2 Final, since that particular exception no longer exists. (I don't guarantee it will completely solve your problem, however.)

Comment: Updating hibernate-core to 6.2.0.Final fixed this issue for me