# WHERE clause for tenantId is missing in SQL

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I have two entities, A and B, a unidirectional OneToOne relation of B (owning side) to A (referencing side). Both A and B are identified by their UUID and tenantId (composite PK).
The domain model (java part) has A <-> B

The application below is a symplified version (using h2) of the full project (using orcacle). Problems are the same.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "b")
public class A {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "UUID", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
  private String uuid;

  @TenantId
  @Column(name = "TENANT_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Integer tenantId;

  @Version
  @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
  private Integer version;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonManagedReference()
  private B b;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "a")
public class B {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "UUID", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(36)")
  private String uuid;

  @TenantId
  @Column(name = "TENANT_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private Integer tenantId;

  @Version
  @Column(name = "VERSION", nullable = false)
  private Integer version;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumns({// CENTRAL PART OF THE PROBLEM (AFAIK)
      @JoinColumn(name = "A_UUID", referencedColumnName = "UUID"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "TENANT_ID", referencedColumnName = "TENANT_ID")
  })
  @JsonBackReference
  private A a;//Table B has a column A_UUID
```

All DB indexes are generated by using at least tenantId and UUID, e.g.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TABLE_A_I0101 ON TABLE_A (TENANT_ID, UUID) LOCAL;
```

So each request (besides native SQL) must contain TENANT_ID without explicitly adding them.

**But**, the generated select misses the TenantId

```
15:38:54.359 [http-nio-8082-exec-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select a1_0.uuid,a1_0.tenant_id,b1_0.uuid,b1_0.tenant_id,b1_0.version,a1_0.version from table_a a1_0 left join table_b b1_0 on a1_0.tenant_id=b1_0.tenant_id and a1_0.uuid=b1_0.a_uuid where a1_0.uuid=?
```

So each **request will perform a full table scan and access between tenants is possible.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>de.cgrau</groupId>
  <artifactId>tenant</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tenant</name>
  <description>tenant</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

Some less relevant stuff neccessary for reproducing the problem.

```
@Component
public class TenantIdResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

  @Override
  public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
    return "12";//Implementation for test purposes
  }

  @Override
  public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
    hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, this);
  }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {//Implementation for test purposes

  private final RepoA repo;

  @GetMapping("/entities/{id}")
  public A getEntities(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return repo.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow();
  }

  @PostMapping("/entities")
  public String createEntity(A a) {
    a.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID()
        .toString());
    B b = B.builder()
        .uuid(UUID.randomUUID()
            .toString())
        .build();

    //mutual
    a.setB(b); // a -> b
    b.setA(a); // b -> a
    return repo.save(a)
        .getUuid();
  }
}
```

Minimalistic application.yml for test purposes:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    defer-datasource-initialization: true
```

Extended hibernate logging, if you want to see the generated SQL too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql" level="TRACE"/>
    <Logger name="org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind" level="TRACE"/>
    <Logger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
    <Logger name="jdk.event.security" level="WARN"/>

    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Tried a lot.
The above code is from [@TenantId referenced by @JoinColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943627/tenantid-referenced-by-)

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'tenant_id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'de.cgrau.tenant.domain.B' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)
```

Tried @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(s) but Just TENANT_ID is a PK/FK and A_UUID is no PK (just FK).
Tried "insertable = false, updatable = false" as recommneded by exception, had to do it for both JoinColumns which results in "A_UUID can't be null".

Try and error with "@MapsId" (@MapsId or @MapsId("tenantId")) like described here:
[JPA @OneToOne with Shared ID -- Can I do this Better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833370/jpa-onetoone-with-shared-id-can-i-do-this-better)

### Edited on 2024-01-03

Tried *@JoinColumnsOrFormulas* (as described [here](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/onetomany-join-on-non-pk-composite-key-not-mapped-to-a-single-property/1530/7)) which suppresses some kind of validation on the column. But this fails with hibernate envers which is required in my context (but not mentioned in the above example yet).

Comment: Because we had to do a workaround, which was not nice, I will not share it. **But** the discussions I found regarding this problem is worth reading:  It might not work because the tenantId filter might not be applied. Read `apply the filter condition to the where clause of a query resulting from find()` from [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16830)